# Is spending 16 years (in total) in academia to get three degrees career suicide? What do I do?

Tags: career-path, early-career

It took me 5.5 years to get my BSc, 3 years to get my MSc, and 6 years to do my PhD. I had a child as a teenager (so I have spent my entire adult life a mum) and we moved countries (to Germany) when I went to do my PhD. 16 years is a long time in University. Now I am looking to start my Post-Doc this fall (at the same institution) and I am trying to figure out my options. I love doing research, but I am incredibly insecure about the time it has taken me to get here. I decided awhile ago that becoming a professor is not for me... is there hope for me in industry? Or am I too old/in school for too long? This is causing me an immense amount of anxiety.

Edit: I should mention that I took around 8 months out (spent the time teaching) in between the BSc and MSc for my child (she got sick and needed surgery) and then it took something around half a year to move to Germany and settle before my start date. Furthermore, I just turned 36. The first two years of my PhD were spent with the lab under construction, and I was building up the fumehood gas lines and experimental setups. It took way longer than originally planned. So really my actual PhD work took 4 years to complete with 3 first author papers at the end.

Comment: What is your phd in? 6 years is average for math.

Comment: Time (like age, duration of study, etc) maters less if you try to reach your goals in your life and receive satisfaction because of your activities. So do not worry. Just enjoy your life and try to be happy.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but maybe valuable information: In many European countries, it is a common requirement for faculty positions that you must have completed your PhD not more than `x` years ago. (This does not affect you at the moment, as you talk about the time from _before_ your PhD.) This requirement typically goes with a note saying that taking time off for reasons similar to what you mention does not count against the `x` years. My impression was that being a mother may also be a valid reason to loosen this time requirement. This all sounds very encouraging for your situation.

Comment: The first two answers here are very good advice. You are only "too old" to start a career (even in academia) if you are already past retirement age. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input! I appreciate it.

Comment: Why did you give up academia as a career? Just because you thought you couldn't or some more essential reason?

Comment: For tenure track positions at my institution (Europe), candidates are evaluated according to their "academic age" which is the time since completing their PhD. So finishing later doesn't put anyone at a disadvantage.

Comment: @cheersmate A warning about Germany in particular, though - for W1 professorships (which tenure track positions normally are), the laws of at least some of the 16 states have conditions on the academic age of the applicants that start counting at the *beginning* of the PhD phase. They are somewhat flexible but still part of the law book. For permanent academic work, if may be useful for the OP to talk about the possibility to stay for a habilitation with their advisor/head of the group.

Answer (score 14):

#### You are doing well --- enjoy the ride

I had a somewhat similar journey to you.  I was also a teen parent and went through university raising two little girls.  The undergraduate program I chose was a long one (6 yrs with honours), and I also had to wait a long time for my PhD dissertation to be reviewed.  I got my PhD conferred a bit over 12 years after I entered university; a bit less than in your case, but not a huge difference in the scheme of things.  In my time in academia I have known one other academic who was also a teen parent, and she also had a hard slog to get her doctorate.  It certainly has its challenges raising children while studying, but it is a very rewarding experience, as you would certainly know.

So firstly, don't be insecure about your circumstances and path through your higher education.  You have raised a child and also trained yourself to do academic research, which is nothing to be sniffed at.  The good news is that now you get to the fun part where you can work as a researcher in a university, and while your peers are just thinking about starting a family, you are already well advanced into this.  As you go through academia you will probably encounter some other academics who also had interesting circumstances through their education; there are a few academics floating around who were teen parents (we were just more advanced than the rest of them!) so you are not alone.  You will also find that there are many other academics who had careers prior to academia, and completed their PhDs late in life.

You don't say how old you are, so it is difficult to offer advice on limitations here, but nothing in what you have written precludes a successful academic career.  There is no need to get ahead of yourself and worry about whether or not you will become a full professor.  In the early stages, just enjoy having a job in the field and use your time to gain mastery over your research area.  As you progress and publish more papers you will learn more research skills and you will then have a better idea of exactly what you want to do.  Enjoy your post-doc position.

Answer (score 2):

If you enjoy what you are doing, don't mind the pay, and don't want to be a professor, then you are doing great for you!

I suggest that you write down why you enjoy your job. When one of the naysayers comes to try to put you down for choosing this, remember your own rationale.

That being said...  the reason most people don't like to stay for extended periods as a Postdoc is the pay, which is typically low. For this reason, most people prefer to go to industry, or to try to find a professorship. However, neither of those come with the independence of being a Postroc. Professors are bound to teaching and funding duties, and industry professionals are bound to the customer's desires.

As long as you are doing work even semi-relevant to industry, I think you would always be able to find a position in industry **if you want**. But the work is much much different than what you are probably used to as a Postdoc. Furthermore, it is my experience that Postdocs have a much more laid back lifestyle compared to industry professionals, which is advantageous with children (although in Germany that point might be mute).

Even direct out of a PhD, you could of course just apply to some jobs in industry to see what they are offering... Remember an interview is also a chance for you to interview the company. You do not need to accept every offer presented to you. It may also help with your self esteem if you get some enticing offers that you can turn down! Just beware that a lot of companies offer positions that they say involve research, but in truth are more tied to customer interactions. The best case is if you know somebody in the company who can give an honest assessment of the work.

Comment: If OP intends to stay in Germany: Postdoc pay isn't really low here. The main issue for most people (and parents in particular) is the lack of long-term job security.

Comment: Postdoc pay in Germany is nice, but still much lower than industry. I know several people that have been Postdocs for more than 5 years in Germany. They enjoy the independence of doing research without the pressure that comes with a professorship. It is definitely possible to have a "long term" postdoc, but this will depend on the funding situation of the specific group. The advantage from the point of view of the professor is that they get a very experienced person that helps to push forward long term projects.

Comment: "Postdoc pay in Germany is nice, but still much lower than industry." Of course. Academia is part of the public sector and salaries are usually lower (but more secure) in the public sector. However, the typical TVL-13 pay is enough to live a comfortable middle class life (and build up some savings).